# External Key Value Pair Data To Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, dictionary

I have an external resource that keeps information as `key-value pair` (say file, typically an xml), I want to load this info into application as a `Dictionary<Key,Value>` (Generics). I'm seeking any serialization-deserialization mechanism or any other better way to do it without any overhead.

Sample for external resource will be as following,

```
  Id         Value

  in         India

  us         United States

  fr         France
```

Comment: what is the problem? is it parsing the xml into pairs?

Comment: I tried by adding custom structure that work intermediate between external stream and found that it is an overhead. Because reading from external, setting to custom class and then making dictionary...

Comment: @omerschleifer exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(say file, typically an xml)`

Assuming you XML as

```
 <root>
    <key>value</key>
 </root>
```

Code to convert it to Dictionary

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse("<root><key>value</key></root>");
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary= new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var el in rootElement.Elements())
{
   dictionary.Add(el.Name.LocalName, el.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary of `string string` should do the trick.

```
// read from XML or some place    

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dictionary.Add("in", "India");
dictionary.Add("us", "United States");
dictionary.Add("fr", "France");
```

Comment: Please check my question again, my key-value pair is external, may b changed each run... This hard coded solution is not work with that

Answer (score 1):

XML

```
<Loc>
 <Id>in</Id>
 <Value>India</Value>
</Loc>
```

C#

```
Dictionary<string,string> map = new Dictionary<string,string>();

XElement xe = XElement.Load("file.xml");

var q = from data in xe.Descendants("Loc")
        select data;

foreach (var data in q)
{
  map.Add(data.Element("Id").Value,data.Element("Value").Value);
}
```